# Howto get memory usage of a started process

Tags: java, memory, processbuilder

I try to get the memory usage of a process started via Java.
Can someone give me a hint how to do it for the example Notepad.exe?

```
    // Memoryusage of the Java programm
    Runtime runtime=Runtime.getRuntime();
    total = runtime.totalMemory();
    System.out.println("System Memory: " + total);

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("notepad.exe");
    Process p = builder.start();
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069303/java-processbuilder-windows-command-wildcard) including

```
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe",  "/C", "tasklist /fi \"IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe\" /NH");
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

this post has your answer
[Java ProcessBuilder memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883729/java-processbuilder-memory)

quoting top answer:

> The new process runs outside the Java process that started it. Allocation of memory to the new process is managed by the operating system, as part of process management.
>   The Java class ProcessBuilder, which provides an interface for starting and communicating with the new process, runs inside the Java process.

Comment: So  there is no other way then starting an other process (also outside of java) to get the memory usage?

Comment: not with java.
you could try solving the problem with c oder c++

Answer (score 1):

You could run a system command and dump it's output in a file.
Then, parse this file to find the memory usage.