# In Java, is it possible to increase the JVM's available memory and/or kill other Java programs?

Tags: java, memory, process, jvm

I'm inexperienced with advanced Java so please bear with me.

I'm curious about Java's ability to implement features that may be termed "autonomic". Say we have two Java programs running. And one program determines that the other one is hogging memory, and thus kills that program and/or allocates more memory to the JVM.

I know in Java you can see what the available memory is (see [How to do I check CPU and Memory Usage in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74674/how-to-do-i-check-cpu-and-memory-usage-in-java)), but what if we want to dig deeper?

Thank You.

Comment: If you're still interested in the "autonomic" features that can be implemented within Java (not just at the command-line level as @Sam suggested), perhaps my answer might be of help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> You Asked:-is it possible to increase the JVM's available memory and/or kill other Java programs?

1. Yes It is Possible You can increase the heap size of `jvm` like :

   ```
         java -Xmx512M ClassName //512M = memory you want to increase
   ```
2. To Kill a Process like : `taskkill /F /IM <processname>.exe`

**Note**
 
->but its not a good idea because the heap may be of a fixed size or may be expanded       depending on the garbage collector's policy.

->open your Command prompt type `taskkill/?` to know the details.

3 . And You can check *total memory* , *free memory* and *max memory* currently reserved by `jvm` 
in this way.

```
          int  MegaBytes = 1024*1024 ;

          long  freeMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / MegaBytes;
          long  totalMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / MegaBytes;
          long  maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / MegaBytes;

          System.out.println("Memory used by JVM: " + (maxMemory - freeMemory));
          System.out.println("freeMemory in JVM: " + freeMemory);
          System.out.println("totalMemory in JVM : " + totalMemory);
          System.out.println("maxMemory in JVM: " + maxMemory);
```

For more information [please check here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#freeMemory%28%29) .

Comment: indeed, it's often of more interest to increase the minimum RAM reserved

Comment: I think the OP wants to increase memory while the JVM is running.

Comment: @sam hey this returning same value everytime i run it on,
Memory used by JVM: 1656
freeMemory in JVM: 118
totalMemory in JVM : 119
maxMemory in JVM: 1774

Answer (score 9):

**1. Increasing memory for JVM**

You can specify the initial and the maximum heap size in Java using the following code..

```
java -Xms64m -Xmx256m ...
```

in this

```
-Xms<size> specifies the initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size> the maximum Java heap size.
```

**2. Checking how much memory easy of your program uses**

There is a very handly tool that is given you when you install jdk in your computer which shows how much memory, heap space all running java programs in taking in your computer.

**Java Visual VM**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/

you can find it in your installed bin folder of jdk.

A previous stackoverflow post should also help 
[Monitoring own memory usage by Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754748/monitoring-own-memory-usage-by-java-application)

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the “autonomic” part of your question, it is indeed possible to do process management from within Java, albeit limited:

- Assuming that all processes to be managed will have always been
  started from within your Java application using
  [`ProcessBuilder.start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start%28%29), you can use the [`destroy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy%28%29)
  method on the process you want to **kill**. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356340/killing-a-process-using-java) for more information.
- Detecting when a process has too much **memory** implies being able to
  gather information about the process. The trouble is that information
  can only be accessed by the operating system. Inevitably, you'll have
  to use some kind of command or third party tool to get it. For
  further info, have a look at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238121/howto-get-memory-usage-of-a-started-process).
- Although vaguely related, shutdown **hooks** allow you to do some
  critical chores automatically when the application closes. For
  instance, saving/closing any document(s)/file(s) left open. You can
  read more in this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639319/java-shutdown-hook/19640087#19640087).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding -XmsMBm when trying to run a program.
eg java -Xms64m ClassName