# Option for running out of memory

Tags: java, arraylist

So, I have:

`LinkedHashMap <String, LinkedHashMap <String , ArrayList<Integer>>> MYMap = new LinkedHashMap <String, LinkedHashMap <String , ArrayList<Integer>>>`

Each `Key` in the hashmap the size of the `ArrayList` will increase by one, and it starts at one. So When I reach key 176 it will have 176 integers in the  `ArrayList`. So Obviously I get out of memory. Now I DO NEED to have ALL of those integers in the array. What are my options. AND if it's increasing the heap size, I need a way that when I do hand this project to someone they do not have to know that they have to increase the size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting JVM heap size at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763295/setting-jvm-heap-size-at-runtime)

Comment: This answer should also help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204757/in-java-is-it-possible-to-increase-the-jvms-available-memory-and-or-kill-other/17204785#17204785

Comment: Alternatively you could try less memory-hungry algorithm

Comment: No idea what you want to do but you should consider using Guava's `Table` -- or build better classes

Comment: It sounds like a choice of algorithm issue. You can increase the heap, but you'll be getting diminishing returns as you need it to get bigger and bigger. You might be able to use a more efficient structure, or you might be able to stream the data, processing smaller pieces independently. Nobody can help there unless you explain the situation.

Comment: Have you looked at BitSet, this uses 1 bit per value instead of the 32-bits per Integer reference in the ArrayList.  If you are adding Integers to the list why are you using String for the key?